# What does the symbol $\ll$ mean?

Tags: numerical-methods

I came across,

> If $|y| \ll 1$, then $x/y$ may have large relative and absolute errors.

I'm not sure what the symbol $\ll$ means. I looked it up on Google and nothing came up.

Comment: $|y| << 1$ means "$y$ is a very small number". It's more or less the same as $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

"... is very small compared to ..."

Answer (score 2):

In engineering and other not-so-strict applications of mathematics the symbol reads 'much less than'.

BTW, it does not consist of a two 'less-than' symbols (`<<` which renders as $<<$), it is a separate $\LaTeX$ symbol `\ll` rendering as $\ll$ (and its counterpart 'much greater than' is `\gg` $\gg$).

For more information and examples see e.g. Wikipedia:

- [Inequality (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics))
- [List of mathematical symbols – Symbols that point left or right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_that_point_left_or_right)
- [Help:Displaying a formula – Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula#Relations)

Answer (score 1):

The symbol can be read as 'much less than'. Thus $|y| << 1$ means ' the absolute value of y is much less than 1'.

Comment: Not exactly. It means 'the absolute value of $y$ is much less than $1$'.

Comment: Oops! Thanks, edited now